# Putting a PNG on the Pi Headlessly

Tags: ssh, headless, data-transfer

so I'm sure someone has an easy answer to this. I'm running a Raspberry Pi headlessly - I can SSH in to its static IP address, while it sits in a box so it can't get damaged. Usually I just send it commands in the Terminal of my Mac. One thing I'd like to be able to do for my specific application is read PNGs into some of the Python code. I can do that fine in terms of the code, and I've put PNGs just directly onto the SD card, but now I want to leave it in the box with its SD card in. How can I get a PNG from, say, my Mac desktop onto the Raspberry Pi in the terminal?

Comment: start a web server on your Mac ... browse from RPi and download files

Comment: You can use **ANY** networking protocol. I use Samba, ftp, ssh or nfs or afp to exchange files.

Answer (score 1):

this is actually super easy, I shouldn't have posted! use SCP. https://howchoo.com/pi/how-to-transfer-files-to-the-raspberry-pi

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.